# How to get Strings read into Strings[] args by specifying the command line arguments?

Tags: java, command-line, io, arguments

I want to populate the String[] array in main() function via the command line arguments. All the Strings are already written into a text file which I am passing to it using the '<' operator at runtime such as-->
java Sort < input.txt

all the Strings are contained inside the file input.txt (which needs to be sorted)--->
zzz bbb ggg aaa fff kkk lll

But this is not happening. I know it can easily be done using java.io but I need this easier way..

Comment: when using a '<' operator, you are providing data to `System.in`, _not_ arguments to `main(String[])`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So more generally, you want to turn the contents of a file into the arguments to a program?

`cat input.txt | xargs java Sort`

Answer (score 4):

Well, you can't, the `<` operator is used to redirect input, not pass the content of a file as command line arguments.

Standard IO is the way to achieve that in this case.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by writing via script that will input the strings from the file and then execute the java command with those inputs.

something like this can work from  a windows batch file

```
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "str="

for /F "delims=;" %%I in (sample.txt) do set str=!str!!%%I%

java Test %str%
```